# How do I re-equip a Gene Tonic?

Tags: bioshock

I've just started playing Bioshock and I've picked up a few Gene Tonics. The problem is this: I didn't figure out how the selection screen worked the first couple of times, and just clicked the slot I wanted it to go into (rather than the glowing "replace" button).

How do I go back to that screen (or equivalent), or is Wrench Buddy lost to me forever?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to find a [Gene Bank](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Gene_Bank) in order to change your equipped plasmids or gene tonics.

Comment: Brief mystery, quickly solved. :)