# How to add Plasmid slots in Medical Pavillion?

Tags: bioshock

This is my second time playing through **Bioshock** (first was years ago on Mac, now on Nintendo Switch). For whatever reason I don't remember this being an issue the first time I played, or maybe I just didn't care as much but... I can't add Plasmid slots at Gatherer's Garden because **I have zero ADAM**.

I am now in the Medical Pavillion and have rescued two little sisters, and I know at least one of them dropped a pink hypodermic needle item of some kind that I was unable to pick up, even when attempting to interact with the **A** button as I walked over it. (Was this ADAM? Why couldn't I pick it up?)

I remember most of the story of this game, but details of the game mechanics are somewhat hazy in my memory, so I'm like a beginner all over again in that regard.

What am I supposed to do? It's frustrating that out of the four abilities I *should* have, I only have two because I have not been able to expand my slots.

**Update:** Also, due to currently having the "wrong" plasmids equipped (neither are Fire), I can't melt the second frozen over area to progress beyond the Medical Pavillion. If anyone knows which objects can be ignited with the nearby torch please let me know, because I have the Telekinesis plasmid and can levitate objects up to the torch. So far nothing I've put to the flame will ignite, not even a corpse (go figure, they burn when alive but not in death).

Comment: [You're not the only one](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bioshock/comments/mln4nb/stuck_in_medical_pavilion_due_to_plasmid_change/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [How do I re-equip a Gene Tonic?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/15735/108916) has as an [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/15738/108916) by [Rawling](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/249/rawling):

> You need to find a [Gene Bank](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Gene_Bank) in order to change your equipped plasmids or gene tonics.

...

And as [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bioshock/comments/mln4nb/stuck_in_medical_pavilion_due_to_plasmid_change/gtn483b/) says:

> Twilight Fields is actually optional, you can always come back to this level.
>
> To switch plasmids, you need a Gene Bank, but the first Gene Bank is in the next level, Neptune’s Bounty.
>
> You can get out of the Bathysphere, Gene Bank, and get back in and return to Twilight Fields.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the area the frozen over passage leads to is optional. I had already completed everything essential in the Medical Pavilion but was hung up on that spot. It's funny to think I could have simply returned to the Bathysphere so much sooner! I guess when the Quest Arrow disappears it means there's nothing left to do but return to the Bathysphere.